# iPhone COREPLOT: Barchart not displaying properly

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, core-plot

In my iPhone app I am implementing coreplot VerticalBar Chart

Though I am taking larger value for Y axis but it is displaying up to certain limit only. As shown in image, it is displaying bar up to N500000 only but actually I am passing larger value. (I am passing value through Graph Array given below).

What could be the problem?

Here is the image and code:

[image]

Here I am passing value for YRange

```
plotSpace.yRange = [CPPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPDecimalFromFloat(-5000000) length:CPDecimalFromFloat(10000000)];
plotSpace.xRange = [CPPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPDecimalFromFloat(0.0f) length:CPDecimalFromFloat(21.0f)];
```

Code for generating Y axis labels:

```
CPXYAxis *y = axisSet.yAxis;
y.axisLineStyle =nil;
               y.majorTickLineStyle = nil;
       y.minorTickLineStyle = nil;
y.majorIntervalLength = CPDecimalFromString(@"2500000");
y.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPDecimalFromString(@"0.0");
```

Here I am giving value of Tick mark Location

```
  NSArray *marginArray =[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                       [NSDecimalNumber numberWithInt:-5000000],
                       [NSDecimalNumber numberWithInt:-2500000],
                       [NSDecimalNumber numberWithInt:00],
                       [NSDecimalNumber numberWithInt:2500000],
                       [NSDecimalNumber numberWithInt:5000000],
                       [NSDecimalNumber numberWithInt:7500000],
                       [NSDecimalNumber numberWithInt:10000000],
                       nil];
```

Here I am giving Label Name:

```
y.labelingPolicy = CPAxisLabelingPolicyNone;
NSArray *yAxisLabels1 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"-N5000000", @"-N2500000",@"N0",@"N2500000",@"N5000000", @"N7500000",@"N10000000", nil];
```

.

```
int labelLocation1;
labelLocation1 = 0;
    
NSMutableArray *custLabels1 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[yAxisLabels1 count]];
NSLog(@" %d",[yAxisLabels1 count]);
 
for (NSNumber *tickLocat1 in marginArray) 
{  
    CPAxisLabel *newLabel1 = [[CPAxisLabel alloc] initWithText: [yAxisLabels1 objectAtIndex:labelLocation1++]  
                                                             textStyle:y.labelTextStyle]; 
    newLabel1.tickLocation = [tickLocat1 decimalValue]; 
    newLabel1.offset = 3.0;//y.labelOffset; 
    [custLabels1 addObject:newLabel1];
    [newLabel1 release];
}
y.axisLabels =  [NSSet setWithArray:custLabels1];
y.majorTickLocations =  [NSSet setWithArray:marginArray]; 
y.title = @"Y Axis";
y.titleOffset = 45.0f;       
      y.titleLocation = CPDecimalFromFloat(150.0f);
```

I am passing this Array for plotting graph:

```
NSArray *roiGraph = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                 [NSDecimalNumber numberWithInt:-5000000],                                                                                                                    
                                 [NSDecimalNumber numberWithInt:5000],    
                                 [NSDecimalNumber numberWithInt:10000000],                                                                      
                                 [NSDecimalNumber numberWithInt:-5000000],  
                                 [NSDecimalNumber numberWithInt:9000000],                                                                                                                                     
                                 [NSDecimalNumber numberWithInt:20005],   
                                 [NSDecimalNumber numberWithInt:50000],
                                 [NSDecimalNumber numberWithInt:7500000],     
                                 [NSDecimalNumber numberWithInt:400000],    
                                 [NSDecimalNumber numberWithInt:220000],     
                                 nil];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look carefully to this line

```
 plotSpace.yRange = [CPPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPDecimalFromFloat(-5000000) length:CPDecimalFromFloat(10000000)];
```

You set length to 10 mln, and this mean that visible area is in (-5 mln to +5 mln). Setup length to other value, 15 mln for you example, and see results again.